# Unable reset settings in .bashrc without stopping updates

Tags: installation, background

I am updating my ports in MacPorts which may take a day.
I have changed my dot -files. I would like to test them without shutting the updates down.

I have `^Z` the installation and restarted my shell. However, I am using Screen such that my settings will not be reset until I detach the whole Screen. This would however stop the installation which I do not want.

I know that there is a command which allows me to put the installation to "background". However, I am not sure

- which is the name of this command (it seems not to be bg)

**How can you put the installation to background?**

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796079/how-can-i-put-a-process-to-background-after-its-execution-with-broken-ctrlz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want `bg` and then `disown`.  This is much as if you'd run the install under `nohup` beforehand.

Comment: I have no manual for bg and disown. I use OS/X.

Comment: I use Zsh. --- This is a great answer about disown: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603696/linux-command-line-best-practices-and-tips/603707#603707

Comment: The new question is at here: http://serverfault.com/questions/35246/how-can-you-see-the-processes-which-you-put-to-background

Comment: @masi: 'jobs' command.

Comment: @chaos: jobs shows me a list of current processes in stack. --- Please, see the bottom of the message: http://serverfault.com/questions/35232/unable-reset-settings-in-bashrc-without-stopping-updates/35245#35245

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to do a

. .bashrc and have it take effect immediately.

Comment: I run everything on Screen. --- This may be the reason your command does notwork.

Comment: You need to be in the same directory as your .bashrc file for this command to work.

Comment: Which version of OSX are you running, anyways?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my process is now at background.

I did

```
...
zsh: suspended  sudo port upgrade outdated
$bg                                                                            ~ 1
[1]  + continued  sudo port upgrade outdated
$disown                                                                        ~ 1
$jobs                                                                          ~ 
$                                                                              ~
```

**[edit]**

My command does not work.

Please see what I get after jobs command

```
...
$disown                                                                                                                                                 ~ 1
$jobs                                                                                                                                                    ~ 
$--->  Building python25                                                                                                                                 ~ 
--->  Staging python25 into destroot
--->  Deactivating python25 @2.5.4_2+darwin_9+macosx    bg5latex      bg5pdflatex 
--->  Installing python25 @2.5.4_6+darwin_9+macosx
--->  Activating python25 @2.5.4_6+darwin_9+macosx

To fully complete your installation and make python 2.5 the default, please run

        sudo port install python_select  
        sudo python_select python25

--->  Cleaning python25
--->  Fetching iso-codes
--->  Attempting to fetch iso-codes-3.10.1.tar.bz2 from http://arn.se.distfiles.macports.org/iso-codes
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for iso-codes
--->  Extracting iso-codes
--->  Configuring iso-codes
--->  Building iso-codes
```

It seems to put stuff to my shell from background. This is strange since I can clear and then run my own commands.

It does not put nothing at the moment to my screen. It apparently needs some time to make it again.

Comment: Your backgrounded process still has your terminal as its stdout/stderr.  You can redirect those using > and 2> when first running the process (or if you use nohup it'll do it for you by default).  I don't know of any way to change a process's stdout/stderr from outside it after it's started, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.