# How can you see the processes which you put to background?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, background

This question is based on [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/35232/unable-reset-settings-in-bashrc-without-stopping-updates/35245#35245).

**How can you see the processes which you put to background?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will show up in a *pstree*

For example:

```
pstree -a -h
```

Comment: @rkt: Thank you for your answer! --- I use OS/X. It does not have the options -ah. What is their purpose such that I can find them?

Comment: -a = show command line arguments, -h = highligt current tree .

Answer (score 5):

The usual way is `jobs`.  However, `jobs` doesn't see background processes which have been `disown`ed, because they aren't attached to your shell any more.  For those, you'll have to look at `ps` in some form or another, perhaps `ps -u`, depending.

Comment: @chaos: Is there any way to get more information about the processes? --- I have http://dpaste.com/62613/ which would not suggest me that there is an installation going on if I did not know that.

Comment: Chaos put it best.  ps -u $username. So if I am logged in as kyleh, I do "ps -u kyleh" to see what is running under my login.

Comment: ps aux gives me more info. --- The problem is then to get the significant info.

Comment: I opened a new question to know how to get significant info about the command: http://serverfault.com/questions/35260/how-can-you-see-clearly-process-data-from-ps-u-user